# Doubts about tasleem after completing Salah

Tags: salat, doubts

After completing Esha salah in congregation I came out from the mosque. Then I started to have doubt about my Tasleem. I am having a feeling that I haven't completed Tasleem. Should I repeat my salah? What to do in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

> Six cases of doubts are such that these can be ignored. Prayer does
> not become invalid in the event of these doubts.
>
> 1. Doubts after having finished the prayer.
> 2. Doubt after passing of the event. For example while in sajdah, to doubt having missed ruku’.
> 3. Doubt after the time has passed. For example, doubt at the time of Maghrib whether the ‘Asr prayer was offered or not.
> 4. People having doubtful natures. Such persons doubt about everything. So they can be doubtful about prayer also. They must
>    ignore their doubts.
> 5. Doubt either by an Imam (one who leads the prayer) or a ma’mum (the follower of the Imam in prayer). In this case the Imam may be sure of
>    his performance but the ma’mum is doubtful or vice versa. In such case
>    whoever is in doubt will follow the one who is sure.
> 6. Doubt during a sunnat (non-obligatory) prayer, or in Salat al-ihtiyat.

[Reference](https://www.al-islam.org/elements-islamic-studies-sayyid-saeed-akhtar-rizvi/lesson-40-shakk-doubts-prayer)